# to_timestamp to store time zone data

Tags: postgresql

I have two columns, one named "date" and the other named "time". Date is a date datatype and "time" is a character datatype. I'm using the following query to select a new combined timestamp column

```
SELECT 
    to_timestamp(concat_ws(' ',air_date,air_time),'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:MI:SS') as datetime
FROM table1
```

This returns the correct timestamp but with "+00" timezone. I want to explicitly tell the query that the timezone is in "EST5EDT" so that I get either "+04" or "+05" for the timezones. I've tried the following but received an error

```
SELECT 
    to_timestamp(concat_ws(' ',air_date,air_time,'EST5EDT'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:MI:SS TZ') as datetime
FROM table1
```

> ERROR: "TZ"/"tz"/"OF" format patterns are not supported in to_date
>
> SQL state: 0A000

How can I select a timestamp column with the EST5EDT time zone info contained within it?

Comment: That doesn't quite work. What happens when I do that is it assumes the input datetime is in "UTC" and then it converts that to "EST5EDT". I need postgres to interpret the input time as "EST5EDT" first, then convert later.

Comment: Sorry, was wrong, for some reason I think that the `to_timestamp` returns `timestamp without time zone`. However your format is supportet by [timstamp input](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT) so you can use the simple cast like `concat_ws(' ',air_date,air_time,'EST5EDT')::timestamptz`.

Comment: according to this it returns 'timestamp with time zone', at least in postgres 9.5: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 0):

If you just add yoru tz to timestamp cast, it will add appropriate amount of hours:

```
t=# select 
  concat_ws(' ','2016-08-16'::date,'10:00:00'::time,'EST5EDT')::timestamptz
, concat_ws(' ','2016-08-16'::date,'10:00:00'::time)::timestamptz;
       concat_ws        |       concat_ws
------------------------+------------------------
 2016-08-16 14:00:00+00 | 2016-08-16 10:00:00+00
(1 row)
```

If I understand you right, you want same date and time with TZ "value" appended? Then this might help:

```
t=# set timezone = EST5EDT;
SET
t=# select 
  concat_ws(' ','2016-08-16'::date,'10:00:00'::time,'EST5EDT')::timestamptz
, concat_ws(' ','2016-08-16'::date,'10:00:00'::time)::timestamptz;
       concat_ws        |       concat_ws
------------------------+------------------------
 2016-08-16 10:00:00-04 | 2016-08-16 10:00:00-04
(1 row)
```